# Merge multiple pre-ordered ArrayLists in to a new Array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, heap

I have 12 pre-ordered Integer[] arrays in 12 files. I'd like to merge them together just like I would in a mergeSort, with the difference that I can't combine them into one array before sorting. I must keep them separate and their size cannot exceed 50.

The requirement is as follows:
Use the merging technique to sort the various chunks with respect to each other and write the output to a file called "result_using_merge.txt".

Use the array of integer primitives called "potentialMinimums" to hold the current minimums and print it at each iteration of the sorting.

How do you suggest I go about it?

SOLVED:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BasicArrayMerger
{
   private static ArrayList<Integer> finalCollection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private static ArrayList<Integer> minCollection;
   private static int[] minIndex =
   { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
   private static int[] maxIndex =
   { 49, 49, 27, 49, 49, 27, 49, 49, 27, 49, 49, 27 };
   private static Integer[] minimums;
   private static ArrayList<Integer[]> inputs;
   static PrintWriter outputStream, runStream;


   static void mergeSortedArrays(final int memorySize,
         ArrayList<Integer[]> inputChunks, Integer[] potentialMinimums,
         String outfile)
   {
      try {
          outputStream= new PrintWriter(outfile);
          runStream = new PrintWriter("resources/RUN_merge.txt");
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      inputs = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(inputChunks);
      int totalInts = 512;
      int processedInts = 0;
      while (processedInts < totalInts)
      {
         minCollection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         minimums = potentialMinimums;

         while (minCollection.size() < memorySize && processedInts < totalInts) 
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) 
            {
               if (minIndex[i] > maxIndex[i])
                  minimums[i] = 9999;
               else
                  minimums[i] = inputs.get(i)[minIndex[i]];
            }

            Integer value = findMin(minimums);

            if (processedInts%10==0)
            {
               runStream.println("\n\n******"+processedInts+" iteration:");
               runStream.println(Arrays.toString(minimums));
            }

            int valueIndex = findMinIndex(minimums);
            if (value == 9999)
               break;
            else
               minCollection.add(value);
            minIndex[valueIndex] += 1;
            processedInts++;
         }

         outputStream.println(minCollection);
         finalCollection.addAll(minCollection);
      }
      outputStream.close();
      runStream.close();
   }

   public static int findMin(Integer[] minimums)
   {
      if (minimums.length == 0)
         return -1;
      int small = minimums[0];
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < minimums.length; i++)
         if (minimums[i] < small) {
            small = minimums[i];
            index = i;
         }
      return small;
   }

   public static int findMinIndex(Integer[] minimums)
   {
      if (minimums.length == 0)
         return -1;
      int small = minimums[0];
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < minimums.length; i++)
         if (minimums[i] < small) {
            small = minimums[i];
            index = i;
         }
      return index;
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a homework.

Comment: @ŁukaszJuraszek You need to show what you have done so far? Show us some code.

Comment: @ŁukaszJuraszek - maxIndex[] is hard coded, should maxIndex be based on the actual file sizes?

Comment: consider using a min-heap of size 12

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?